# sum last values and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have "steps" table like this

```
id | points | game_id | price | user_id | timestamp | some | additional | fields
```

it contains game information.

I have a code which can group by game_id

```
SELECT game_id, MIN(timestamp), 
(SELECT points FROM steps as t2 WHERE t2.game_id = t1.game_id ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1) as last_point  
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY game_id
```

but I want to group by price and summarize each last point of the game. my query is

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT game_id) as game_count, COUNT(id) as step_count, SUM(points), price
FROM steps WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY price
```

But this query returns a sum of all points while I need a sum of the last point in each game.
Please point me to the right way

Example result

```
last_points_sum | game_count | step_count | price
200             | 2          | 3          | 100
400             | 3          | 4          | 200
```

where table is

```
id | points | game_id | price | user_id | timestamp
1  | 10     | 5       | 100   | 1       | 100000001
2  | 200    | 5       | 100   | 1       | 100000002
3  | 200    | 6       | 200   | 1       | 100000003
4  | 0      | 6       | 200   | 1       | 100000004
5  | 400    | 6       | 200   | 1       | 100000005
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik postgres

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks. I've just added examples. could you please check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?
This assumes that timestamp is unique, at least for each instance of game_id.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT game_id) AS game_count,
    COUNT(id) AS step_count,
    SUM(COALESCE(ltIsLastPoints, 0.0) * points),
    price
FROM
    (SELECT
        game_id ltGameID,
        MAX(timestamp) ltTimestamp,
        1.0 ltIsLastPoints
    FROM
        steps
    GROUP BY
        game_id
    ) lt RIGHT JOIN
        steps
    ON ltGameID = game_id
    AND ltTimestamp = timestamp
WHERE
    user_id = 1
GROUP BY
    price;
```

Your description says you want to group by points but your example query groups by price. I went with price.

Comment: thanks, I've just did a mistake with group by. you are right, I tried to group by price.

Comment: your query looks awesome! how I can extract additional data? for example timestamp or game_id

Comment: Since you're grouping on price and I don't see how aggregating timestamp or game_id would make sense. Are you maybe looking for the last timestamp and/or game_id for each price? You could add MAX(ltGameID) and MAX(ltTimestamp) to the outer SELECT clause. Note that they may not refer to the same game though. To do that would require more work.